# Exclude File from Uncommitted Changes

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, visual-studio-code

I have a config.debug.json file that I update frequently based on which server I'm pointing to. Is there anyway to exclude this file from Uncommitted changes? In sourcetree and vs code it shows up as an uncommitted change, but I never want to commit the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `config.debug.json` to your [`.gitignore`](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/). This will exclude the file from source control, which should prevent it from showing up in the changes section for vscode and sourcetree

**Update**

If you've already added the file at some, you first need to untrack it by running:

```
git rm --cached config.debug.json
```

This will leave the file on your system but stop tracking it

Comment: hmm. Tried putting src/config.debug.json in .gitignore but the file still shows up in changes.

Comment: Did you commit the file at some point? If so, to remove it from tracking, run `git rm --cached src/config.debug.json`